# MVC Inserir texto numa label quando o botão é selecionado

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Prentendo preencher uma label quando clico num botão. Criei um metodo, uma label e um botão. O objectivo é que ao primir o botão, a label seja preenchida com os dados que recebo.

Tenho praticamente tudo funcional, mas ao clicar no botão ( usando no navegador eu obtenho os resultados), mas eles não são inseridos na label, ou seja, não aparecem como é desejado.

**Método**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetEmails()
        {
            ProjetoEntities entities = new ProjetoEntities();
            var emails = (from Utente in entities.Utente
                          select Utente.Email);
            return Json(emails);
        }
```

**Botão**

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Select All"/>
```

**Label**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="Destinatário" placeholder="Para:">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Email/GetEmails/',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#email').html(data);

                    console.log(data);
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao inves de usar:

```
$('#email').html(data);
```

Use:

```
$('#email').val(data);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Resultou !!!